# How to select rows from bottom of the Table without any sorted parameters....?

Tags: c#, sql, query-performance

I have a table with 10,00,000 records (say daily log-in history saved & sorted )

- I need to find the last log-in details (with respect to date & employee id) which is stored at the down side of the table.
- How do I write a query (`SELECT` query) which finds the rows (search by bottom to top and selects rows)

Actually I want to increase the speed of execution...

```
if Order-By / Group-By is used this orders after selecting rows...
```

How to do it?

Please give some select query which works really.... in C#

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 2):

It would be more efficient to order your results in descending order and then restrict your results to the top n

```
var table = new Collection<Foo>();

var results = table.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).Take(10).ToList();
```

This would evaluate to a sql query that wouldn't need the full record set in order to satisfy the result, only the most recent records.

Of course, without knowing what fields are available the above is a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the last 10 logins like:

```
SELECT top 10 * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY login_date DESC
```

Comment: This query needs to be written in c# presumably using LINQ or a LAMBDA expression.